# How to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm building an ANN model, but first I need to normalize the data and add a normalization layer before I build the neural network.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data for IL V2.csv', encoding = ('ISO-8859-1'), low_memory= False)

#Split features from labels
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)
train the model to predict.
train_features = train_dataset.copy()
test_features = test_dataset.copy()
train_labels = train_features.pop('x_CO2')
test_labels = test_features.pop('x_CO2')

#The Normalization layer
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
print(type(normalizer))
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try `normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features).astype('float32'))` in the last line and see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: Tha actully fixed the problem. Thank you so much.