# How to convert a NumPy error to a Tensor in a DNN model?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

follow up on the previous question (Check this link: [How to convert a NumPy error to a Tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73242809/how-to-convert-a-numpy-error-to-a-tensor))

I tried to build the DNN model:

```
#Regression with a deep neural network (DNN)
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
model = keras.Sequential([
  norm,
  layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
return model

dnn_model = build_and_compile_model(normalizer)
dnn_model.summary()


history = dnn_model.fit(
 train_features,
 train_labels,
 validation_split=0.2,
 verbose=0, batch_size = 32, epochs=10)
```

This is the error that I get when I run the model:

```
history = dnn_model.fit(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Comment: What is the type of `train_features`?

Comment: And it's the exact same error as the question you have linked. Why don't you try using the same solution?

Comment: `train_labels.astype(np.uint8)`? or another int type